# Login in Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle

Do I have to surround the user id or the password with special chars or does it work like this**:**

`con.ConnectionString = "User Id=uid;Password=pSw;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1234)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = db)))";`

In case of which special character I have to use the escape sequence?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be like this: 
       `con.ConnectionString = "USER ID=uid;PASSWORD=pSw;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1234)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = db)))";`